# Display public_html folder automatically

Tags: php, linux, apache, unix, virtualhost

I'm building local apache2 web server. Here is part of my VirtualHost file.

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.chinchaladze.ge

    DocumentRoot /var/www/chinchaladze.ge
    <Directory />
            #Options FollowSymLinks
            #AllowOverride None
            #Options FollowSymLinks
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/chinchaladze.ge>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

As I know, when I will go to www.chinchaladze.ge , it should automatically find the public_html folder and find index.* file there. But instead, it shows me a default "Index of /" webpage, similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgze8.gif

Can you somehow help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
Options Indexes
```

is responsible for showing the browsable directory structure as seen in your image upload. It is advised to remove this setting from all productive servers.

Use

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php welcome.html
```

to make Apache display your index file.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings